# jQuery .remove() on DOM object with no parent

Tags: jquery

**Solution**

```
var $tcMain = $(this).children().not('.tc-remove').clone()
```

**Problem**

From an HTML element, we are pulling a jQuery object, and wish to remove all elements with the class `.tc-remove` within it for further insertion.

Our current code:

*HTML*

```
<div class='tc'>
  <p> To be kept </p>
  <div class='tc-remove'> To be removed </div>
  <span> To also be kept </span>
</div>
```

*jQuery*

```
$('.tc').each(function(i,v){

  // Clone and strip redundant elements
  var $tcMain = $( $(this).clone().not('.tc-remove') )


  $create = $('<div>').append($tcMain.html())

})
```

We would prefer the .html() to not be necessary!

Comment: Can you add a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Have you tried $('.tc-remove').remove() ?

Comment: @KyleMuir Done. Please see http://jsbin.com/aqalef/1/. Jonast of course!

Comment: Your JSFiddle is either out of date, or something else is wrong - it contains of a selector that will never match anything because the class name *tc-tab-only* is not used, it should be *tc-remove*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is a lot simpler than you might expect :)

You've got nodes that are not in the DOM yet, and you want to filter them. Set the object to itself filtered:

```
  $tcMain = $tcMain.not('.tc-remove');
```

Now, you'll only be adding the elements that don't have the class `.tc-remove` .

Comment: So, `var $tcMain = $( $(this).not('.tc-remove').clone().html() )` ?

Comment: It didn't! Doing the `.html()` at insertion now, rather than when forming the DOM... very annoying!

Comment: @NickPrice What I meant is  `$(this).clone().not(".tc-remove")`

Comment: Interesting! Still doesn't get around the `.html()` problem though.

Comment: @NickPrice What `.html()` problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34655/discussion-between-nick-price-and-benjamin-gruenbaum)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$tcMain.remove('.tc-remove');
```

Comment: .remove() works only on children. The jQuery object has no parent element, rather a list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `filter` and not `find`

```
$tcMain.filter('.tc-tab-only').remove();
```

As you are looking for the elements that are at the same level of the selector and not the descendant of it.

And the way you are cloning the elements is wrong.
Supposed to be

```
var $tcMain = $($(this).clone());
```

**Code**

```
$('.tc').each(function (i, v) {

    var $tcMain = $($(this).clone());
    $tcMain.find('.tc-remove').remove();

    $('body').append($tcMain);

});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JASkS/2/)**

Comment: That's intentional- we don't want the whole element- just the children.

Comment: @NickPrice.. Why is that you are targeting the wrong element in the example

Comment: Do you want the element to be removed from even from the main `tc` from which others are cloned .. http://jsbin.com/avovip/1/edit

Comment: I want the *contents* of `.tc` (EXCEPT `.tc-remove`) to be useable for a DOM insertion elsewhere -- The fiddles are all extremely simplified! Currently I'm having to do the `.html()` at time of insertion, when I'd rather just get the jQuery object correct before this.